# How to focus on a curve in Oxyplot?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, plot, oxyplot

So I have a plot with curves of multiple different scales - some small, some large. A user focuses and zooms into one. Now he wants to focus on other curve. We have a reference to the curve and PlotModel it is placed in. So I wonder does OxyPlot provide facilities for centering and zooming so that entire selected curve would fit into view?

Answer (score 0):

you must set min/max (y/x)axis.

use AbsoluteMaximum, AbsoluteMinimum,Maximum  and  Minimum